# neo4j-shell-tools and arrays

Tags: arrays, neo4j, export

I used the neo4j-shell-tools to export a Neo4j graph to a graphml file. 
Everything worked fine, except that the array properties have not been exported correctly, as they have been treated as strings.

For instance, my nodes have an array property called "locations", whose values are a list of geographic locations.
In the output graphml file, the value of the property "locations" for a node is as follows:

[Ljava.lang.String;@58ad67b9

It seems that array properties are not supported by the neo4j-shell-tools. Has anyone has any issues with that? Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that internally just the `toString()` method is run on the property value. In case of an array the JVM uses the snippet you've provided as string representation. Consider filing an issue on github for this.

Comment: I created a fork of the project and modified to add the support for array properties to the commands import-graphml and export-graphml.
I also sent a pull request. 
I've just used my version of the tools to export a database with 2 million nodes and 21 millions links and it worked just fine. Array values are correctly exported and imported.

Comment: Excellent. Maybe you want to share your modifications as a pull request? We ask contributors to sign our CLA, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cla.html.

Comment: Yes, I did share my modifications as a pull request. As for the CLA, no problem for signing it.